# htaccess if directive does not work

Tags: htaccess

The following directive appears to fail in that it results in a 403 error. The server supports version 2.4 of Apache.

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^(.*)?/uploads/(.*\.txt)#">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

The objective of the directive is to deny all requests and/or execution of text files in the directory "upload". The htaccess file is in the root of the web directory.

Based on the documentation from [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html) the syntax is correct and should work.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^.*/uploads/.*\.txt#">
    Require all denied
</If>
<Else>
    Require all granted
</Else>
```

Comment: The code block including the one in the question exhibits peculiar behavior in that it works intermittently i.e. there is no failure however text files remain accessible.